# Parsing XML string in Java without OOM error

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I'm using Karaf and ActiveMQ Artemis in Docker, and one of my routes gets an XML string on a message queue, and I need to extract an element. But I'm getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

I've narrowed the issue down to one of these lines.

```java
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    Object[] args = exchange.getIn().getBody(Object[].class);
    JmsMessage message = (JmsMessage)args[0];
    String s = message.getBody(String.class);
    ...
}
```

I'm wondering what my options are to get around this error.
Looking at the `free -m` output inside my container,

```
# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          23948       11579         498        1316       11870       10690
Swap:          6143         240        5903
```

There's 10GB of RAM available plus 6GB in swap.  The Artemis queue has `<max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>` and no `<global-max-size>` set.  So there's no explicit limit.  Possibly, this leads to a max of `-Xmx / 2`, according to the comments in the `broker.xml` file.  It looks like the default is -Xmx2G so this would mean 1GB max.  Note that the message is nowhere near that size.  It's just 5MB of binary files saved in XML using Base64 for the binary.

So I will look into starting the AMQ with higher `Xmx`, but otherwise, is there any option in Java to deal with parsing the `String`, (or `JMSMessage`) in such a way that it doesn't overflow the heap?

i.e. like streaming it, or buffering it, instead of loading the entire String into memory?

Comment: How do you extract the string?

Comment: Is everything running in the same JVM or do you have separate JVMs for Karaf and ActiveMQ Artemis? In what JVM is the OOME happening?

Comment: Hi Justin, they are started in separate JVMs, but inside the same docker container, using supervisord.  I know it fails in those lines because of debug statements. So the OOME happens in Karaf, technically, while trying to load the String in memory.  Simon - the error happens before the extraction, which I just do with String.substring/indexOf.

Comment: I've upped the Karaf Xmx from 1024mb to 2048mb. Will see if that helps.

Comment: Success.  Karaf needed more RAM.

Comment: To be clear, given that the OOME is happening in Karaf (where the client is presumably running) which is running in a separate JVM from ActiveMQ Artemis the memory configuration of ActiveMQ Artemis is not relevant.

Comment: Correct, thanks, I realised that, hence upping Karaf, and leaving AMQ as is.

Comment: Since you've solved this problem you should add an answer and mark it as correct to help any other users who run into this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by increasing the RAM available to Karaf, under /bin/setenv

```
export JAVA_MAX_MEM=2048M
```